# I want to drag and drop an image out of a "div" into antother div (dropzone) with HTML5

Tags: php, html, drag-and-drop

like I described in my title I want to drag an image out of a "list" (which is actually just a div where i load images into out of a database) and want to drop it in a "dropzone".

Hopefully everybody understands my english.

My problem is: Im totally new to JavaScript and HTML5 and my application works just partly.

I drag the image and drop it into the dropzone ... so far so good ... but the image transfered is gone out of my list --> i just want to copy/clone the image.

After a picture is placed in the dropzone, my functions just appends the pictures in the dropzone .... i know that "appendChild" has something to do with it, but I dont know how to work this out.

So it would be very nice if somebody can help me?!

JavaScript Code:

```
//controls the beginning of an drag-event
function dragStart(ev)
{
    ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed= "copyLink";
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.getAttribute("id"));
    return true;
}

//handles the dropzone
function dragEnter(ev)
{
 //avoids placing the element somewhere else (instead of in the dropzone)
    event.preventDefault();
    return true;
}

//handles dropping an element before the target area
function dragOver(ev)
{
    return false;
}

//handles the actual drop part (not working)
function dragDrop(ev)
{
    var eleid = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(eleid));
    ev.preventDefault();
    ev.returnValue();
}
```

HTML:

-Tag:

```
<img id="person_id_'. $metaData["meta_id"] . '" draggable="true" "ondragstart= "return dragStart(event)" src="'. $path .'"/>
```

Dropzone:

```
<div id= "dropzone" ondragenter= "return dragEnter(event)" ondragover= "return dragOver(event)" ondrop= "return dragDrop(event)"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is really a task for jQuery. Pure HTML5 can't really do much more than represent DOM elements. JavaScript is the modifier for the DOM language, at least; the most convenient one :)
jQuery got most of the complex tasks you want figured out (also in the major browsers) and there should not really be any concern to not use it.

Check these docs:

- http://jqueryui.com/draggable/
- http://jqueryui.com/droppable/

Dropables can accept draggables from other DIV elements, like so: http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option

Luckily the internet is filled with hundreds of different examples for almost every jQuery function/sub-api. Try Google some examples, it's super easy to learn.
In this case jQuery-UI is an extension of the main jQuery library, but it's really straight-forward. Just add in the SCRIPT-tags and you're read to go!

Comment: The problem I`ve got is that Im not allowed to use frameworks as jQuery ... so is there any possibility to handle this with pure html5 and javascript code?

Comment: Is it a school assignment or does your work restrict from working with it? You can download the Developer versions of jQuery en jQuery-UI and just look at their sources. It's very clean and well-documented. You can exactly see there how the makers of jQuery did it from plain JavaScript, and coolest of all, they are paying a lot of attention to cross-browser compatibility :). And btw; for what you want to achieve no "HTML5" is perse needed. HTML5 is just a more streamlined version of XHTML that corrected tons of issues HTML4 had.

Comment: The jQuery source is the perfect place to find your drag-drop answers. There is no misunderstanding in your questioning. You are new to this stuff, like you said yourself, so how can you confirm my advise is not the right answer? Good luck on reading that book ;)

Comment: This might sound harsh, but you are just being lazy here. If you don't read up and do research you can never achieve much in the scripting/programming world.

Comment: Alright dude! The problem is ive been putting alot of effort in this when it comes to research etc. but like i said im new with javascript and all i wanted is just a simple hint what i have to change and maybe the reason why ... this has nothing to do with lazyness or what it is called ...